# White space at the top of the page

Tags: screen-layout

How can I get rid of the white space at the top?
Thanks in advance.[image]

If the img is not showing: On top of my page, there is an empty white space, how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Is it showing only for logged-in users?

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a BOM-Error or encoding error due to file transfer in filezilla.
See this post for more information.

[BOM Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554445/how-to-fix-byte-order-mark-found-in-utf-8-file-validation-warning)

Comment: There is no trace of a BOM in the screenshot.